# Replacing elements of span using jquery

Tags: jquery, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [text replace with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197195/text-replace-with-jquery)

I am just starting to learn jQuery. One of the problems asks to manipulate the elements within span so something like

```
<span class=test> 1a 2b 3c</span>
```

into

```
<span> 1A 2B 3C </span>
```

Where `A` replaced `a`.

Somewhat related is, how to determine the length or number of elements within the span.

### Edit

Some clarification. What I'm really looking for isn't just to turn lowercase to uppercase, but to to go into the span element and find specific character(s) and replace them with something else.

Comment: What's your question?  Is this homework?

Comment: @OP: You should get into the habit of wrapping your classes in quotes

Comment: you need the `myString.replace()` function... Welcome to `Regular Expressions`! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
  var text = $('.test').text();
  var uppercaseText = text.toUpperCase();
  $('.test').text(uppercaseText);
});
```

This will execute and convert it on page load.

Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't work.  Replace .val() with .text() or .html() and it will work.  .val() is for inputs with values, not for tags with contents.

Comment: yeah, i had some wires crossed.. was working on a form on my other monitor :)

Comment: It happens.  I consult with php.net and jquery.com... pretty much constantly.  :)

Comment: Note that if you have multiple spans with the same class, `uppercaseText` will be the sum of the text in all the spans, repeated multiple times.  Better to use `.each` and also, for better performance, select `span.test`.

Comment: @Stefan - Thats for him to decide how he semantically constructs his function. I just gave him a solution that will fix according to his test data

Comment: Yes you did.  However as he stated, he is obviously a novice re jquery.  Since classes are typically shared between elements in a page, I think it helps to point out that your solution will not give the correct result when that is the case.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but could you look at my edit?

Comment: And yes, the class is used repeatedly.

Comment: Maybe you should state your question clearer, because it certainly came across that you wanted to convert the contents to uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

This gets the length and changes the content.

See it live: http://jsfiddle.net/H8DsW/

```
<span class="test"> 1a 2b 3c</span>​
<script>
$(function() {
  alert($('.test').html().length);        
  $('.test').html($('.test').html().toUpperCase());
  $('.test').removeAttr('class');    
});
</script>​
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but could you look at my edit?